# probability set theory expansion

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory

How do i prove:
$$
P(A ∪ B ∪ C) = P(A)+ P(A^c∩B)+P(A^c∩B^c∩C)
$$
knowing that:
$$
P(A∪B∪C)=P(A)+P(B)+P(C)-P(B∩C)-P(A∩B)-P(A∩C)+P(A∩B∩C)
$$
thank you in advance.

Comment: You could also prove the statement $A\cup B\cup C=A\sqcup (A^c\cap B)\sqcup (A^c\cap B^c\cap C)$ directly by element chasing and mentioning why $A,A^c\cap B,$ and $A^c\cap B^c\cap C$ are in fact disjoint (*here $E\sqcup F$ denotes the disjoint union of $E$ and $F$, i.e. it is $E\cup F$ while calling to attention that $E\cap F=\emptyset$*).  The right side should be a big hint as to how to set up the cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

Note that $$P(A^c∩B)=P(B)-P(A∩B)$$
And $$P(A^c∩B^c)=P((A \cup B)^c)$$
I think you can continue from here.

Comment: thank you very much, i didn't knew those properties so it was a little bit difficult. But know i already solve it. Thank you again.